# My projectile doesn't well replicate on multiplayer with Unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4, multiplayer, blueprint

I recently started to learn how to use Unreal Engine 4.
I begin to well understand how it works, but I just encountered an obstacle.... The Multiplayer.

So, for the moment I just made a Blueprint that can dash and throw a fireball. To test the multiplayer, I want that both users (server and client 0) have the same player to fight. so I replicated the character movements, variables and everything that goes with it. I run events on servers (run on server) and Locally too. I well replicated the obstacle too, with it's variables and events.

For the dash, there is absolutely no problem. player 1 can dash and we see it on both screen, and same for player 2.

But, when player 2 throw the projectile, in fact, it's player 1 which is throwing the object.

On the screenshot, I try to throw the projectile with player 2 (left) from his screen (left too). But as you can see, on the player 1 screen, we see that it is player 1 which is throwing it.

Does anyone has an idea to fix it?

I hope I've been clear enough. Tell me if you want more information or screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I think my problem comes from the fact I have a "get player controller" that takes the index 0. but the index never change dynamically.

Comment: That is true get player controller intake the index of the player but i believe there is a node to retrieve the index of a local player (may need to double check to be sure)

Comment: okay so I shouldn't use this on multiplayer. I tried what you told me but it didn't worked. Also I've posted a new topic where i've better explained my problem. I think it is more clear. here is the link if you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902940/what-should-i-use-instead-of-get-player-controller-to-make-a-multiplayer-game